# Undo git reset --hard after commit but before push

Tags: git

I unknowingly did a `git reset --hard` after commiting my changes but before doing a `git push`.

I didn't committed all my files and now changes in those uncommitted files are lost. `git status` shows only untracked files.

I am trying to bring back those changes and then i need to undo my commit as well since i need to do a `git pull` first.

How do I undo this?

Comment: What is the problem? Just after a commit, you *should* generally only have unmodified and untracked files, right? What specific effect of the subsequent `git reset --hard` do you want to undo? Or did you not include all changes in your commit?

Comment: Not clear what you want. May be `git reflog` will help you

Comment: pull, merge, push? Is there an actual problem?

Comment: @hvd Sorry for the incomplete problem statement. Please see the updated question

Comment: @AlexeyTen Sorry for the incomplete problem statement. Please see the updated question

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry for the incomplete problem statement. Please see the updated question

Comment: Is it the case that you did more work after committing your files?  Does `git reflog` have any commits that may be helpful?

Comment: @Makoto No it was a case where I did some work on multiple features and was committing them separately. When after a commit my push got rejected because I needed to pull again. By mistake I ran git reset --hard and lost my uncommitted changes.

Comment: @SurenderThakran. Thanks for updating the question. Close vote retracted. Sorry to say that there is no adequate solution to your problem.

Comment: didn't understood the reason for downvote :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't committed all my files and now changes in those uncommitted files are lost.

Sorry to bring the bad news, but then Git cannot help you recover those files. Content that has at some point been tracked by Git is generally recoverable, but if it was never in Git in the first place, you are out of luck.

Your system may or may not have built-in snapshot functionality. If it does, and you enabled it, you can use that for recovery.

Your project may or may not copy files to temporary build directories. If it does, and you have not yet performed a new build, you can use that for recovery.

But from Git itself? No, there is no way.

> then i need to undo my commit as well since i need to do a git pull first.

Undoing commits is done with `git reset`, but as you found, it is a dangerous command if used with the wrong options.

Get the commit right, then use `git pull --rebase` instead.

Comment: But they were a part of git. Since changes in my tracked but uncommitted files are lost. Not in untracked files. Or do you mean that even then they are not recoverable?

Comment: The files were tracked by Git, but the particular content you've lost now wasn't.

Comment: okk got it. This indeed is a bad news. Thankfully it wasn't a substantial work. One more thing, to undo my commit should i use git reset <commit-hash> and then redo my work, would it work?

Comment: @SurenderThakran In this particular case, I would use `git commit --amend` to fix your earlier commit, and then as I mentioned in my answer, use `git pull --rebase` to reapply it to the latest remote commit. I would not use `git reset` for this at all. But if you do want to anyway, then yes, `git reset` can work, so long as you use either `--mixed` (the default) or `--soft`, not `--hard`.